# How to manually refresh a rxjs timer and update parameters of the observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm making the pagination of a web that shows data updated every 2 minutes from an API (the API is paginated but I need to do my own pagination to show the data as I want, example: 100 elements per page, page number 5, that would show elements from 401 to 500).

```
private readonly _start = new Subject<void>();
private readonly _stop = new Subject<void>();
lista : any = [];
pNum = 1;
act = timer(0, 120000);

constructor(private ListaService:ListaService) {
 this.act.subscribe(() => {
  this.ListaService.getLista(this.pNum,'usd').pipe(
    takeUntil(this._stop),
    repeatWhen(() => this._start)
  ).subscribe(resp=>{
    this.lista = resp
  });
 })
}

start(): void {
 document.body.scrollTop = 0;
 this._start.next();
}
stop(): void {
 this._stop.next();
}
```

So the thing is, when I click the button to change the page, the methods stop() and start() are called, and also the variable pNum is updated with the number of the page selected. I thought that doing this would load the data of the page selected but it's not happening, the data updates 2 minutes after I click the page number when the timer triggers.

Is there any way to manually refresh the timer and update the parameters of the observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, modify your `act` to include a source for "manual" updates, thus:

```js
manual$ = new Subject<void>();
act = merge(timer(0, 120000), this.manual$)
```

Then whenever you need a manual update, call `next` on `manual$` thus:

```js
this.manual$.next();
```

**EDIT**

While we're at it, don't nest `subscribe` calls - use a flattening operator (`switchMap` is suitable in this case), thus:

```js
 this.act
   .pipe(switchMap(_ => this.ListaService.getLista(this.pNum,'usd')))
   .subscribe(resp => this.lista = resp);
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eaeedt?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for demo.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to be working. The timer is not working anymore as it is not refreshing the data every 2 minutes like before. Also the data is not refreshing manually, pNum is updating correctly but the method of the service ( getLista() ) looks like its not picking the new value of pNum.

Comment: Remove your `_start` and `_stop` shenanigans, you don't need them.

Comment: Already removed those. I made a new method named refresh() which is called when a page is selected, that method calls this.manual$.next() but nothing happens. And I don't know why now because of the merge (I suppose) is not refreshing every 2 minutes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used `merge` wrong - edited with fix.